# Spring Kafka Producer to Consumer lag

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Hi we are using spring Kafka for producing and consuming messages.The topic has 6 partitions.On doing a load testing with 500,1000 messages being posted to the topic we see that the consumer receives it at a lag of 1 sec or more.
Also our application is deployed in two servers.So we have kept the concurrency of the Consumer to be 3.So 3 consumers on one server and 3 on other.We see two problem here.

1. We observe a lag of 1 seconds or more for each message.This is observed even on sending 1 message from producer to consumer.
2. On seeing the splunk logs ,we observe that event processing is happening on only one server not both.Means consumer logs are seen on one server only.

We are not setting any specific producer and consumer properties.So consumer and producer should be using the default configuration.Also we have verified that the producer distributes the load to all partitions.

Any help or suggestion in this regard is highly appreciable.

We even manually changed the consumer and producer properties as shown in image attached.But no luck.

Comment: Where are you getting the consumer lag value from? Through the Kafka UI? Or are you measuring it yourself?

Comment: I have put a logger on producer and consumer side.So calculating the time difference of the two

Comment: That may not be the best way; the value you measure would include the time required for the Spring application to produce the message and read it from the topic. You should read the timestamp field from the [ConsumerRecord](https://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/ConsumerRecord.html) and set the [message.timestamp.type](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#topicconfigs_message.timestamp.type) property to LogAppendTime. This will give you the time when the message reached Kafka.

Comment: @TylerLiu But i am storing the timestamp after producing the message.And at start when it comes to the consumer.Also we see that event processing is happening in only one server.What about that?

Comment: 1) Kafka producers do not immediately send to Kafka. There is a synchronous buffer flush before ever reaching the broker, so no consumer will be immediate consuming 2) Please show your code as a [mcve]